Using plural for appendix if more than one
Consider the following code, which adds the plural word appendices rather than appendix, if there is more than one appendix. I have added Babel and German, just for testing and a google translation for the plural.
Question:
In the MWE I step the appcntr manually after every section. How can I modify \refstepcounter so that if a boolean \if_is_appendix_bool is true it will automatically do so?
% compile three times 
%\documentclass[numbers=nodotatend]{scrartcl}
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\ExplSyntaxOn
 \makeatletter
  % Singular will be changed by Babel
  % provide translation only for plural
 \tl_set:Nn\appendixname{Appendix}
 \tl_set:Nn\appendicesname{Anhänge}
 \cs_set_eq:NN \orgappendix\appendix
 \newcounter{appcntr}
 \tl_set:Nn\appendixmax{0}
 \tl_set:Nn \appendix
   {
     \orgappendix
     \if_int_compare:w \use:c{appendixmax}>1   
         \tl_set_eq:NN\appendixname\appendicesname
     \fi:
   
     % Just for testing
     \tl_set:Nn\thesection{\itshape\Roman{section}}
     \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\appendixname} 
   }

\AddToHook{enddocument/afterlastpage}{
\immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\gdef\string\appendixmax{\theappcntr}}
}

\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
%
% Testing 
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\long\def\testarticlelike{%
%\chapter{My Chapter}
\section{First section}
%\stepcounter{appcntr}
\label{sec:first}
some text is here

\appendix
\section{First appendix}
\stepcounter{appcntr}
\section{Second appendix}
\stepcounter{appcntr}
}

\testarticlelike

say something
\end{document}


why use a second counter, can't you just compare the section counter?

@DavidCarlisle  I can probably use it if I save its state before \appendix is issued, otherwise it will have the wrong value. with a new counter just start from 0, I thought it was easier. I am open to solutions.

normally you reset the section counter in appendices anyway so all you need to do is check it's bigger than one at the end, but if you keep the section numbering just seeing if it is more than 1 bigger by the end is far less intrusive than making a second counter step every time you step section

@DavidCarlisle  Makes sense, will give it a try.

@DavidCarlisle  Worked nicely, just changed to      \if_int_compare:w \arabic{section} >1             \tl_set_eq:NN\appendixname\appendicesname      \fi:

\value better than \arabic  also it would be more idiomatic to use \int_compare:nNnT rather than expose the primitive if...\fi syntax.

@DavidCarlisle  Please post your comments as an answer so we can close the question.

I don't think you need a second counter you could just see if the section counter is bigger than 1 at the end (or if you don't restart section numbering at \appendix compare the values at that point to the end, so

\int_compare:nNnT{\value{section}} >1 
                  { \tl_set_eq:NN\appendixname\appendicesname }



I'd not add the page number for the “Appendix” entry in the TOC: it's useless and also quite difficult to get right.
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

%\setlocalecaption{english}{appendices}{\countcheck{appendix}{Appendix}{Appendices}}
\setlocalecaption{german}{appendices}{\countcheck{appendix}{Anhang}{Anhänge}}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\countcheck}{mmm}
 {
  \cs_if_exist:cT { count@appendix }
   {% don't fail at first run
    \int_compare:nTF { \use:c {count@appendix} > 1 } {#3} {#2}
   }
 }

\AddToHook{enddocument/afterlastpage}
 {
  \immediate\write \use:c {@mainaux}
   {
    \gdef\string\count@appendix{\arabic{\cs_if_exist:cTF{chapter}{chapter}{section}}}
   }
 }

\AddToHook{cmd/appendix/after}
 {
  \addtocontents{toc}
   {
    \string\contentsline
     {\cs_if_exist:cTF{chapter}{chapter}{section}}
     {\string\appendicesname}{}{appendix.A}\string\protected@file@percent
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{My Chapter}
\section{First section}

some text is here

\appendix
\chapter{First appendix}
\chapter{Second appendix}

\end{document}


If I remove the second appendix, I get

With the article class
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

%\setlocalecaption{english}{appendices}{\countcheck{appendix}{Appendix}{Appendices}}
\setlocalecaption{german}{appendices}{\countcheck{appendix}{Anhang}{Anhänge}}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\countcheck}{mmm}
 {
  \cs_if_exist:cT { count@appendix }
   {% don't fail at first run
    \int_compare:nTF { \use:c {count@appendix} > 1 } {#3} {#2}
   }
 }

\AddToHook{enddocument/afterlastpage}
 {
  \immediate\write \use:c {@mainaux}
   {
    \gdef\string\count@appendix{\arabic{\cs_if_exist:cTF{chapter}{chapter}{section}}}
   }
 }

\AddToHook{cmd/appendix/after}
 {
  \addtocontents{toc}
   {
    \string\contentsline
     {\cs_if_exist:cTF{chapter}{chapter}{section}}
     {\string\appendicesname}{}{appendix.A}\string\protected@file@percent
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{My Chapter}
\subsection{First section}

some text is here

\appendix
\section{First appendix}
\section{Second appendix}

\end{document}




Thanks. I agree that is difficult to integrate, especially to generalize it, but is one of those things that I have to do. Thanks also for extending it as you did.
